# paint() on Java applet is set to endless loop. How do I avoid my methods from doing the same?

Tags: java, swing, repaint, japplet

I'm creating a game and I want some of the image to be repainted while others to stay constant. I had put my methods in the `paint()` on java applet but this seems to access the methods in an endless loop.

How do I create a "driver method" that will access my methods but also use the `draw()` at the same time?

```
public void paint (Graphics g)
{
    bufferGraphics.clearRect (0, 0, dim.width, dim.height);
    //mainScreen ();
    g.drawImage (offscreen, 0, 0, this);
} // end Paint method

public void update (Graphics g)
{
    paint (g);
}

public void main (String[] args)
{
    game ();
}
```

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://pscode.org/sscce.html).  2) this code should probably not be overriding the `update()` method.  (It is hard to say with no SSCCE) 3) `bufferGraphics` That is almost certainly the wrong way to go about custom painting.  Don't cache `Graphics` objects if they come from the applet. 4) Why does this applet have a `main(String[])`? 5) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://pscode.org/sscce.html).  (Yes I know I mentioned that in point 1 - it was worth repeating.)

Answer (score 2):

Overriding paint() and update() is done when using AWT. Since you are just learning about painting why not write a Swing applet and extend JApplet, since Swing is more commonly used these days? Then custom painting is done by extending JPanel or JComponent. Then you add this component to the content pane of the JApplet, just like it was a JFrame.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Custom Painting](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) for more examples of painting with Swing.

Comment: "..since Swing is more commonly used these days.."  Which in turn means that many more people feel qualified (& motivated) to offer assistance on Swing GUIs.  Most people that worked with AWT components have forgotten the finer details, and many recent GUI developers have never used them.

Comment: "Since you are just learning about painting why not write a Swing applet(?)"  BTW - though the OP mentioned 'applet' a number of times in the title & message body, they also chose the `japplet` tag.  ;)  The `swing` tag was added by jleedev.